# Rails, devise, current_user get posts.name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have Post model which is associated with devise's User. I want to know names of the posts user has when logged in.

```
  <% @posts.each do |post| %>
     <% if user_signed_in? %> 
        <%= current_user.posts.name %>
     <% end %>
   <% end %>
```

Why this doesn't giving me a post name? and how to make it right?

Comment: What is your model relation

Comment: post belongs_to user;    user has many posts

Comment: do you want to see all the posts of current user?

Comment: since `user` `has_many` `posts` , the `current_user.posts` will return `Array`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your models relation is user has_many posts then only use following code. It may works

```
     <% if user_signed_in? %> 
        <%= current_user.posts.each do |post| %>
         <%= post.name %>
        <% end %>
     <% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks! Just small correction <% current_user.posts.each do |post| %> ...with no equal sign